# How can azure devops build pipeline be triggered when a new image is available on different container registries?

Tags: azure, azure-devops

Let's assume that we have 3 different container registries. Is there any available azure devops jobs/tasks that can provide a way to trigger my build pipeline when a new image is pushed on any of these 3 registries?

I have some insights with MS Flow but i want to limit the scope on azure devops.

Find a way or recommendation to trigger the build pipeline using devops jobs/tasks.

Comment: What is your container registries?

Comment: @ShaykiAbramczyk Azure Container Registry

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create in Azure Container Registry a web hook that trigger the build in Azure DevOps when new image pushed.

For this you need to write a service with Web API that handle the API Post calls. the ACR web hook send a Post call to the service when new image is pushed.

In the service you trigger the Azure DevOps build pipeline using the Azure DevOps [.Net Libraries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/integrate/concepts/dotnet-client-libraries?view=azure-devops) (if the service is in C#) or with [Azure DevOps Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops).

How to create ACR Web Hook? find [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-registry/container-registry-webhook).

How to trigger build pipeline from code? find [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/88f5959f-118b-4d69-9797-8c762e2744e7/queue-vnext-build-from-c-using-rest-apu-on-premise).

Comment: to sum it up. The idea here is to create a new webapi that implements Azure devops library that accepts the post messages from the webhooks to trigger the build. This is a very nice approach. I will put this on the table and plan to review it. But also, FYI, I'm avoiding 3rd party middleware on this kind of process. your suggestion is the best so far but i'm creating a work around here if i were to follow this. Do you have any other suggestions / recommendations before i accept your answer?

Comment: I don't get anything else in my mind... except for the second answer given here that it's easier workaround but that's not the right way ti use release. I used Azure DevOps service hooks in the past and is not difficult.

Comment: I will be reviewing this and if i found some interesting stuff or alternative for this i will be posting it here. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

you can have releases triggered with new images in the docker hub ([reading](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/release/artifacts?view=azure-devops#sources)). I dont think the same can be done for builds. You can create a release that would get triggered on the new image and that release would talk to the API to trigger the build.